# Is there a mistake in datasheet connection?

Tags: power-supply, power, zener, linear-regulator

In the application diagram shown below for [LM723H](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/LM723), is the connection from Vout pin missing? Shouldn't be shorted to output?
[image]

The internal block diagram is as follows:

[image]

Iam assuming below is the equivalent circuit of the above application (The below circuit doesn't have any error amplifier or 'explicit' feedback control though)

[image]

**Does Rs correspond to the series pass transistor (circled)? Iam confused since Fig 1 seems like R4 is equivalent of Rs.**

Answer (score 2):

> In the application diagram shown below for LM723H, is the connection from Vout pin missing?

No.  A shunt regulator operates differently from a series regulator.

In the first circuit, 100% of the possible output current comes through R4 (the upper right R4).  The equivalent resistance of T1 and the load impedance are in parallel, and form the shunt leg of a 2-resistor attenuator.  R4 is the series leg.

Based on feedback through the non-inverting input, the base drive to T1 is adjusted such that the output voltage is a constant.  Without T1 and feedback, if the current through the load decreases, the output voltage would increase.  With T1 and feedback, the control loop increases the drive to T1, and T1 *shunts* more of the available current to GND, bypassing the load, keeping the load voltage constant.

You are correct:  Rs in the third schematic corresponds to R4 in the first schematic.

Comment: Ok. I think I understood the above explanation.
But Iam unable to understand what role does Vz play in the shunt regulator application diagram( 1st figure). Whether I drive T1 from Vz or Vout pin ( leaving the other pin open), does it make any difference?

Comment: Vout and Vz voltages are only differing by a constant value

Comment: Using the Vz output to drive T1 keeps the output of the error amplifier from having to swing down to less than 0.5 V above GND to turn down the T1 base current.  Back in the day, that was hard to do.  The problem is the common mode input voltage range of the error amplifier - there is a lot of stuff between the N.I. input pin and GND.