# In the below application diagram, what is the point of having the transistor in series with a Zener diode?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, analog, zener, linear-regulator

This is a follow-up of an  [earlier question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/611363/is-there-a-mistake-in-datasheet-connection).

Does it matter whether I drive the transistor T1 using Vout or Vz? (Keeping the other terminal open.)

Don't the Vout and Vz potentials differ by just a constant when the Zener is in series? I am trying to understand, why it is important to use the Vz terminal,  especially since Vz is not available for the TO-100 package.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1):

Minimum Vout is only guaranteed to be 2.0V according to the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm723.pdf).

Anything more than 0.7V or so will turn that ancient TO-66 metal case transistor 'on', so it won't work properly as a shunt regulator. The Zener subtracts 6.2V from that so it will be able to turn off (but the LM723 will require a relatively high supply voltage). You could replace the Zener with something like a green LED, for example.

LM723 is a part that is very long in the tooth. If  you need a power shunt regulator for some reason there are probably better options, such as the (also old) TL431, plus a PNP transistor.

Answer (score 0):

Vz was intended for negative Linear regulation or high voltage (>7) positive shunt regulation.  This reduces power dissipation of the IC and relies on the external series pass transistor for linear power dissipation.

[image]
Vz is not used for basic 2 to 7V positive regulation.

[image]

- this device is not Low in the modern sense of "low" for an LDO with a 3V drop but does have excellent specs for Rout (30 mohm typ) and noise rejection.